# javascript modal not showing on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

please help, i am trying to make a modal, but it doesn't work 
when i click save, the modal is not hide
when i click edit, the modal is not showing
when i put all the function outside document.ready function, all modal can show no error. but when i put it inside document.ready funcion, all modal wont work. when i use console, it gets me error
$(...).modal is not a function

here is my script using jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){        
    load_data_response_gateway();
    var mytable = $('#mydata').DataTable();    
    var csrf_hash = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>';

    function check_response_gateway($rcode){
      var result="";
      var id_response_gateway=$rcode;
      $.ajax({
      //some ajax function
      });
      return result;
    }
```

//load data

```
    function load_data_response_gateway(){
    $.ajax({
                type        :   'ajax',
                url         :   '<?php echo base_url()?>base_setup/response_gateway/get_data_response_gateway',
                async       :   false,
                data        :   {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':csrf_hash},
                dataType    :   'json',
                success     :   function(data){
                                csrf_hash      = data.csrf_hash;
                                if  (data.rCode == '00') {
                                    var html = '';
                                    var i;
                                    var no=0;
                                    var data_delete='';
                                    for(i=0; i<data.result.length; i++){
                                        no=i+1; 
                                        data_delete = [data.result[i].oid, data.result[i].id_response_gateway];

                                        html += '<tr>'+ 
                                                '<td style="text-align: center;">'+no+'</td>'+
                                                '<td style="text-align: center;">'+data.result[i].id_response_gateway+'</td>'+
                                                '<td style="text-align:center;">'+
                                                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-info btn-xs item_edit" data="'+ data.result[i].oid+'"> <span class="fa fa-edit"></span> </a>'+' '+
                                                    '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs item_delete" data="'+[data_delete]+'"> <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> </a>'+
                                                '</td>'+
                                                '</tr>';
                                    }
                                    $('#show_data').html(html);

                                }
                                else{
                                    $('#show_data').html('');
                                }
                                console.clear(); 
                            }                       
             }); 
 }
```

this is my Save script,

```
    $('#btn_save').on('click',function(){
    var id_response_gateway =   $('#id_response_gateway_add').val();
    $.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        url      : "<?php echo base_url('base_setup/response_gateway/action_insert_response_gateway')?>",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data     : {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>':csrf_hash, id_response_gateway:id_response_gateway},
        success  : function(data){
                    csrf_hash   =   data.csrf_hash;
                    if  (data.rCode == '00') {                          
                            $('[name="id_response_gateway_add"]').val("");
                            $('#ModalAdd').modal('hide');
                            swal("SUKSES!", 'Data Berhasil Disimpan', "success");                                 
                            //$('#mydata').DataTable().fnClearTable();
                            load_data_response_gateway();     
                    }else if  (data.rCode == 'bb_03' ) {
                                swal("Warning!", data.check_validation , "error"); 
                    }else{
                        check_response_gateway(data.rCode); 
                    }                        
        }
    });
    return false;        
 });  
  });
```

//close doc ready function

```
  <!-- call jquery-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js';?>"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js';?>"></script>
  -->
  <!-- call DatePicker-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/admin/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css';?>">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/admin/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js';?>"></script>
  <!-- call datatable -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'assets/DataTables/datatables.min.css';?>"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/DataTables/api/jquery-3.3.1.js';?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/DataTables/api/jquery.dataTables.min.js';?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'assets/DataTables/datatables.min.js';?>"></script>
```

really need any help right now.

Comment: try commenting out `jQuery.noConflict();`. It removes `$` as `jquery` alias so you might be receiving this error `$(...).modal ` is not a function.

Comment: //jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
i've done that, it insert the data, but the modal still not hiding after success